# How can I change the scores to make interaction effect in two way ANOVA significant?

Tags: anova, spss, interaction

My question is how to make an interaction effect become significant in two-way ANOVA.

If my main effect A has an F value of F(1,80)=25.5 for example, and my main effect B has an F value of F(3,80)=15, but my interaction effect has a value of F(3,80)= 2.06 which is not significant, how do I change the score in my SPSS data file to make the interaction effect become significant so that I can run further interaction contrasts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow: Are you asking for how to make a non-significant effect significant by changing original data? Or is there something that prevents you from running specific contrasts in SPSS when no interaction happens to be significant at the 5% level?

Answer (score 3):

It does not make sense statistically to modify data to make an effect significant. If you mean change the threshold for significance that would be a different matter.  But I do not understand why having one interation non-significant would prevent you from looking at other interactions.